# Primeflex + PrimeNG tab + PrimeNG tree - unable to make tabPanel grow

Tags: css, flexbox, primeng, primeng-tree, primeflex

Could someone help me with the layout of those PrimeNG components?

I would like to have a tree taking the whole vertical space (minus buttonset at the bottom), scrolling if needed. Tree is being places inside a tab panel.

Thanks in advance

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-np8of7?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Do you want your `tabPanel` to take the whole available height?

Comment: yes; I have done that already by changing p-tabView display from block to flex and making height 100%; but then tab headers are positioned incorrectly; adding flex-direction: column to p-tabView helped - now I need to make p-tree growing to fill the space

Comment: why setting a style within app.component.css for .p-tabview {display: flex} is not effective?

Comment: Try with `:host ::ng-deep .p-tabview {display: flex}`

Comment: thx; now I know about angular styles isolation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can add this kind of CSS

```
.p-tree {
  height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

but in order to apply it, you have to declare `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component definition. See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhqrmm?file=src/app/app.component.css).

Either you just add in your CSS:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-tree {
  height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks; I guess there is more to be done if I wouldn't like to calc it but make it flex-grow?

Comment: Yes, indeed but now, you know how to deal with PrimeNG CSS :)

Comment: It seems undoable using flexbox :(